# GPSD with UBX protocol from ublox

Tags: gpsd

I want to use gpsd daemon in Ubuntu 18.04 with the ubx binary protocol. The ublox F9p GPS chip can output NMEA strings but due to operational reasons I only want to use messages in ubx format. However, when I connect the GPS to the ubuntu system I see no output on "cgps" command whereas i could see the output when NMEA messages were enabled. The manual pages of gpsd claim that it works with ublox as well as NMEA ( This can be verified using the bash command "gpsd -l")

Secondly, on gpsd-clients manual page it claims to have ubxtool (a utility) to check ubx messages received from a port. But although I installed and updated gpsd and gpsd-clients on ubuntu 18.04, it still doesn't recognizes ubxtool as a valid command.
I will be grateful if someone can guide me about these two problems.
Thanks!

I am using gpsd v3.17 with Ubuntu 18.04 as this is the lastest version of gpsd I am able to intall using apt-get

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ubxtool doesn't appear even as a stub until a little over a year after 3.17 was released. It would be suggested to upgrade to 3.18 or better yet build from the gitlab repository. Ublox binary has multiple versions it is possible that the messages from the F9P were not supported by gpsd at that time. Oh, and gpsd 3.18 would not have been released even in time for ubuntu 18.10 inclusion, making 19.04 the earliest it might've been available.